# Returning multiple ajax response on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to have my ajax respond multiple values based on the dropdown I selected.

Here's my JS updated

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#student_infor').change(function()
        {
            var first = $('#student_infor').val();
            var req = $.get('frm_get_stud_record.php', {dd: first,action: 'ajax'});

            req.done(function(row)
            {
                var whatever = JSON.parse(row);
                $('#studen_title').val(whatever.stu_title);
                $('#student_first_name').val(whatever.stu_first_name);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And here's my ajax php

```
    <?php
$ajax = false;
$dbValue = 1; //or the default value of your choice - matched to the default selection value of the dropdown
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'ajax' && isset($_GET['dd'])) 
{
    $dbValue = intval( $_GET['dd'] );
    $ajax = true;   
}
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "college_school_system";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT distinct a.stu_unique_id,
                        a.stu_title,
                        a.stu_first_name,
                        a.stu_middle_name,
                        a.stu_last_name,
                        a.stu_gender,
                        a.stu_email_id,
                        a.stu_mobile_no,
                        a.stu_dob,
                        b.stu_course_id,
                        b.stu_batch_id,
                        b.stu_section_id,
                        c.course_name,
                        d.batch_name,
                        e.section_name
                      from stu_info a INNER JOIN stu_academics b
                      ON
                      a.stu_unique_id = b.stu_acad_stu_info_id
                      inner join courses c
                      ON
                      b.stu_course_id = c.course_id
                      INNER JOIN batches d
                      ON
                      b.stu_batch_id = d.batch_id
                      INNER JOIN section e
                      ON
                      b.stu_section_id = e.section_id 
                      where a.stu_unique_id = $dbValue
                      ORDER BY d.batch_name DESC";//die($sql);
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$title = '';
$f_name = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){



    $f_name = $row['stu_first_name'];
    $m_name = $row['stu_middle_name'];
    $l_name = $row['stu_last_name'];
    $title  = $row['stu_title'];
    $gender = $row['stu_gender'];
    $email  = $row['stu_email_id'];
    $mobile = $row['stu_mobile_no'];
    $birth  = $row['stu_dob'];
    //$title     =  "$title";
    if($ajax) echo $title;
    if($ajax) echo $f_name;
    }
  //die($dataTable);  

?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to have the Ajax return multiple values so i can insert those returned values in their respective input type text boxes.

Comment: just `echo json_encode($row);` and then parse the JSON on the javascript return function. After that you should be able to just loop or assign the values manually.

Comment: Can I ask how can I achieve that? I'm not as good on ajax. Thanks

Comment: I already returned the whole row. Now my problem is how to parse it. Please be clear with your advice. Thanks.

Comment: In your ajax return function, you use `var whatever = JSON.parse(response);` which allows you to fetch the array you echoed from php.

Comment: I did this one. ` $('#student_infor').change(function()
           {
               var first = $('#student_infor').val();
               var req = $.get('frm_get_stud_record.php', {dd: first,action: 'ajax'});

               req.done(function(row)
               {
                   var whatever = JSON.parse(row);
               });
           });`

Comment: How can I now, assign those parsed data inside a php variable.

Comment: Just do `console.log(whatever);` after the parse. You can see your array. Use `$('.title').val(whatever.title);` to set the value. Something like that.

Comment: I did this.var whatever = JSON.parse(row);
                   $('#studen_title').val(whatever.stu_title)
                   $('#student_first_name').val(whatever.stu_first_name)
 but only shows the stu_title. I cannot seem to show the stu_first_name in its textbox which is the student_tittle

Comment: Post what you currently have, form, Ajax, and php

Comment: I'll update my post.

Comment: Post updated. I posted my JS

Comment: Let's see what you have now for your php.

Comment: Also show your form fields. If possible what your row array looks like.

Comment: Sorry. Sort of lesser person when it comes to english. Hehe. I ca't understand english real well. This one `<input type="text" id="studen_title" class="form-control" name="studen_title">` shows the student title based on your instructions. But this one `<input type="text" id="student_first_name" class="form-control" name="student_first_name">` does not show the result.

Comment: Got it. I need to have a unique ID. IF I have 2 input type with the same ID then it will now display on the second box but instead it will appear on the first. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Alright well glad you got it worked out!!